# Phonegap Jquery Mobile and Xcode

Tags: jquery, ios, xcode, mobile

Right now I am developing an iPhone app with jquery mobile. I want to know if i can make different page in xcode like a normal native app and link to that page from my jquery mobile app. So basically most of my apps pages will be made with jquery mobile except for one. Is it possible to seamlessly transition between phonegap and objective c like this using cordova 1.8?

What I am doing is making a recipes app, and I want make a kitchen timer page within the app. Here the user could set up their own countdown kitchen timer that would sound an alarm when done. And I want to be able to link to the kitchen timer directly from the recipe pages. For example if the recipe says cook for 20 minutes I would include a link to the kitchen timer page that would activate the timer for 20 minutes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can write a native plugin with PhoneGap if you need to : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide this allows you to swap away from the jquery mobile. Are you sure your needs are so complex though? Just add another .html page to your www/ folder without referencing jquery mobile and that might be simplest?

Comment: I think @boobyWomack aproach is right, you might need to add a new .html instead.